# What is the exact criteria to get Facebook API Error Code: 100 Error Message: Viewer cannot message specified recipients?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

when I try to send message using facebook api to a certain user, I get the following error: Error Code: 100 Error Message: Viewer cannot message specified recipients.

I thought I get this error when 1:I'm not a friend of the recipient and 2:he set his "who can contact me" setting to "friends of friends" or 3:set his "whose message do I want filtered into my inbox?" setting to "strict filtering".
However, I was able to send a message who satisfies all the 3 conditions above. So my guess seems to be wrong.

Does anybody know exactly when we get the Error Code: 100 Error Message: Viewer cannot message specified recipients?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a parameter valid for another method (feed, post), but not for send. Check the valid parameters in the send dialog reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog